Difference between crf and cq settings in ffmpeg
What is the difference between -crf and -cq parameters of ffmpeg? I am trying to compress 1080p h264 videos into 1080p h265 videos with high quality and low size. I have noticed that in some guides they use -crf while in others they use -cq + -qmin + -qmax.
I have tried researching the difference and all I could come with is that with -crf the size is a bit lower because it reduces data for scenes with fast actions that the person watching would not notice while with -cq that is not the case. Is that it? Are there any more differences? If I have used a number with -crf would the result be similar if I were to use the same number with -cq?
Thank you.
